# 2x2 matrices with sum of diagonal entries equal zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the set of 2x2 matrices with sum of diagonal entries equal zero a vector space over the real numbers under the usual matrix matrix  addition and scalar matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can check it directly or note that the set is given by

$$
\left\{ \left.
    \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}
        \right| \, a_{11} + a_{22} = 0
\right\}
$$

and so it is the set of solutions to a linear homogeneous equation and thus a vector space of dimension $4 - 1 = 3$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I was wondering for a long time how to make the set theoretic brackets to match the size what they surround.

Comment: but a11+a22 must be zero. Diagonal entries sum is zero

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't matter which linear equation you write - the solution space will still be a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Set of all matricess of below type with a,b,c $\in \mathbb{R}$  \begin{bmatrix}
    a &  b\\
    c & -a\\
    \end{bmatrix}
are the $2 \times 2$ matrices of trace zero form a vector subspace of $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ with dimension 3. Since, there are three free arbitrary constants(a,b,c). Vector addition and scalar multiplication closed under usual matrix addition and scalar with matrix multiplication.